# Laplacian of a radial function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, laplacian

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be a radial function, i.e. $f(x)=f(r)$ with $r:=\left\|x\right\|_2$. As stated at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator#N_dimensions) $$\Delta f=\frac{1}{r^{n-1}}\frac{d}{dr}(r^{n-1}f')$$ What's the most elegant way to prove this fact?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On the one hand,

$$\frac{1}{r^{n-1}}\frac{d}{dr}\left(r^{n-1}f'\right) = \frac{1}{r^{n-1}} \left( (n-1)r^{n-2} f' + r^{n-1} f'' \right) = \frac{n-1}{r}f' + f''$$

On the other, the gradient of $f$ is $\displaystyle \nabla f = \frac{\vec{r}}{r}f'$ and thus the Laplacian of $f$ is

$$\nabla^2 f = \left( \frac{n}{r}  - \frac{\vec{r}\cdot\vec{r}}{r^3}\right) f' + \frac{\vec{r}\cdot\vec{r}}{r^2}f'' = \frac{n-1}{r}f' + f''$$

Therefore $\displaystyle \Delta f = \frac{1}{r^{n-1}}\frac{d}{dr}\left(r^{n-1}f'\right)$.

---

I don't know the history of writing the Laplacian of a radial scalar field this way. But it does make certain calculations fast. For example, in 3D do the scalar fields $f_1(r) = A/r$ or $f_2(r) = B/r^2$ have zero Laplacian?

It also makes calculating the Fourier transform of such a Laplacian easier.

Comment: I wouldn't exactly call that elegant...

Comment: What is $\stackrel{\to}{r}$? And why is $\Delta f=\frac{\stackrel{\to}{r}}{r}f'$

Comment: $\vec{r}$ is the radial vector; in Cartesian coordinates, $\vec{r} = (x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$. Of course $r = || \vec{r} ||$, the Euclidean norm. 
$$\nabla f = \left(\frac{\partial\ }{\partial x_1}f, ... \frac{\partial \ }{\partial x_n}f \right) = \left(\frac{\partial r }{\partial x_1}\frac{df}{dr}, ..., \frac{\partial r }{\partial x_n}\frac{df}{dr}  \right) = \left( \frac{x_1}{r}f', ..., \frac{x_n}{r} f' \right) = \frac{\vec{r}}{r}f' $$
@Sergio, if you have a more elegant proof, by all means let's see it! This one is short, which has its virtues ;-)

Comment: Yes of course, the most natural way is to just do the calculations... I'll try to see if I can come up with something fancy

Comment: In the equation for $\nabla f$ above? It's correct as written.

Comment: @SimonS I came up with something if you want to check it out and give me your opinion.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an alternative, it uses some heavy machinery (if some points are unclear perhaps the comment at the end might help) but casts a little light on the symmetry of the situation.

Let's distinguish $f$ from $\phi$ with $f(x)=\phi(\|x\|)$, and from now on we fix $x$ and put $\|x\|=r$. $B_{r}$ is the ball centered in the origin with radius $r$

We have that
\begin{equation*}
s_{n}r^{n-1}\phi'(r)=\int_{\partial B_{r}} \nabla f . \vec u
\end{equation*}
where $\vec u$ is the normal vector to $\partial B_{r}$, and $s_{n}$ is the surface area of $\partial B_{1}$.

By divergence theorem
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\partial B_{r}} \nabla f . \vec u = \int_{B_{r}} \Delta f
\end{equation*}

But
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(\int_{B_{r}} \Delta f\right) = \int_{\partial B_{r}}\Delta f
\end{equation*}

So
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(s_{n}r^{n-1}\phi'(r)\right)=\int_{\partial B_{r}} \Delta f
\end{equation*}

Since $\Delta f$ is also a radial function
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{s_{n}r^{n-1}} \int_{B_{r}} \Delta f= \Delta f(x)
\end{equation*}
which concludes our proof (the $s_{n}$ cancel out).

A first problem with this argument is that it makes use of the fact that $\nabla f(x) = \phi'(\|x\|)\frac{x}{\|x\|}$ and that $\nabla f$ is also a radial function. Proving this properly requires more or less as much calculations as computing directly the laplacian. But this properties can be easily seen when picturing a radial function. The gradient must be orthogonal to the plane tangent to $B_{r}$ in $x$ (because $f$ is constant on $B_{r}$), so it is colinear to $x$ and must have norm $\phi'(r)$. The laplacian can be expressed from the local mean of $f$, so it should by invariant by isometry by radiality of $f$ and hence only depend on $r$.

The advantage of this proof is that it gives a faint idea of why a $r^{n-1}$ goes in and out the expression of the laplacian: the radiality of $f$ makes it possible to compute the laplacian on the whole $\partial B_{r}$ at once and not only in one point, so the $r^{n-1}$ appears when taking means over the $\partial B_{r}$.

Comment: Fun. The fact that the Jacobian of a Cartesian to polar coordinate system is always proportional to $r^{n-1}$ is part of the 'geometric intuition' as to why this happens, for me at least. It's nice to see more formally how that plays out.

Comment: Yep ! Perhaps one can prove this laplacian formula with a polar change of coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment yet I'll point out here that in the last equation of the second answer (the one right before "which concludes our proof") I believe there's a typo and the integral should be evaluated over the border $\partial B_r$ of the ball $B_r$, and not on the ball itself, otherwise the last equation would simplify to $\phi^{'}(r) = \Delta f(x)$, which makes no sense.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1948621)

Answer (score 0):

You can read the section1.3 in [Here](http://www.sci.brooklyn.cuny.edu/%7Emate/misc/laplacian_polarcoord_higherdim.pdf), they proved that in the polar coordinate (here $r_n$ just means the $r$ in n-dimension.)
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n D_{x_i}^2=D_{r_n}^2+\frac{n-1}{r_n} D_{r_n}+\frac{1}{r_n^2} \Lambda_n
$$
where $\Lambda_n$ is a second order differential operator involving only the angular variables $\phi_2, \phi_3, \ldots, \phi_n$, (i.e., it does not involve $r_n$ ). Its proof is based on induction, since for radial symmetric function, we don't need the angular variables, so the only thing left is  $\Delta f=\frac{1}{r^{n-1}} \frac{d}{d r}\left(r^{n-1} f^{\prime}\right)$.